# Calculating mean curvature and Gaussian Curvature from these formulae

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, differential-topology, vector-analysis

I'm following a tutorial designed by a professor.. .  All errors and misunderstandings are mine.

I'm looking at formulas that could potentially allow me to calculate the mean curvature here denoted J, and the Gaussian curvature denoted  K for a sphere.

The formulas are as follows.

$J = -[ \vec\nabla u^1 \cdot \hat{N_1} +  \vec\nabla u^2 \cdot \hat{N_2} ]$  This should be  $\frac{-2}{r}$

$K = (\hat{N_1} \times \hat{N_2}). (\vec\nabla u^1 \times \vec\nabla u^2)$  This should be $\frac{1}{r^2}$

I am taking

$\vec\nabla u^1$ to be $\vec\nabla u^\theta$

$\vec\nabla u^2$ to be $\vec\nabla u^\phi$

furthermore,

I am working from

$r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}$

$\theta = \cos^{-1} (\frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}})$

$\phi = \tan^{-1} \frac{y}{x}$

and that

$x = r \sin{\theta} \cos{\phi}$

$y = r \sin{\theta} \sin{\phi}$

$z = r \cos{\theta}$

I interpreted

$\vec\nabla u^1$ to be $\vec\nabla u^\theta$  = $ \hat{x^i}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} \theta$

and

$\vec\nabla u^2$ to be $\vec\nabla u^\phi$  = $ \hat{x^i}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} \phi$

and

$\hat{N}$ to be $ \frac{< r \sin{\theta} \cos{\phi}, r \sin{\theta} \sin{\phi} , r \cos{\theta}>}{|< r \sin{\theta} \cos{\phi}, r \sin{\theta} \sin{\phi} , r \cos{\theta}>|}$

and

$N_1 = \frac{\partial \hat{N}}{\partial \theta}$

$N_2 = \frac{\partial \hat{N}}{\partial \phi}$

I computed by hand but I did not get the right answer. I have also computed with Mathematica but I am getting something else.

[image]

[image]

This leads me to believe that I am misinterpreting the formulas or something please set me straight.

Comment: I caught one error. In the actual computation, I did not have the radical in as in ${cos^{-1} \frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}}}$ for $\theta$

Answer (score 0):

After a small nap and random conversations about flying cars, I finally got back to this and showed first by hand, then with Mathematica that these formulas are true. Here is a picture.

One gets the -2/r

the other is straightforward to compute too.

[image]

[image]